# Disabling and enabling a timer causes a second instance?

Tags: c#, timer

I have a Start and Stop button on a form that start and stop a repeating SQL query which sends data to a pubnub channel.  When I fire up the form and click start, I see what I expect on the subscribed clients.  However, if I click stop then start again, I now get duplicate data.  A third time gives me triplicate data, etc.  What is causing this?  Here are the start and stop methods:

```
private void btnQuery1Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    lblQuery1Status.Text = "Status: Running";
    btnQuery1Start.Enabled = false;
    txtQuery1Interval.Enabled = false;
    btnQuery1Stop.Enabled = true;
    query1Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(doQuery1);
    query1Timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuery1Interval.Text) * 1000;
    query1Timer.Enabled = true;

}
private void btnQuery1Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnQuery1Start.Enabled = true;
    btnQuery1Stop.Enabled = false;
    txtQuery1Interval.Enabled = true;
    query1Timer.Enabled = false;
    lblQuery1Status.Text = "Status: Stopped";
}
```

I can post `doQuery1` if necessary, but it's using an `OdbcConnection` and data reader to get a single integer result then it's serializing it with `Newtonsoft.Json` and sending it using `Pubnub.publish()`.  I'm hoping though that this is something obvious I'm just missing in the `btnQuery1Start_Click()` method above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you have a single timer - but you're adding an event handler to it every time you click start:

```
query1Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(doQuery1);
```

Just move that line into wherever you construct the timer, so it only gets added once, and it'll be fine.

(I'd personally rewrite it as `query1Timer.Elapsed += doQuery1;`, but that's your call...)

Comment: Thanks for not only telling me what's wrong but how to fix it!  I figured it was something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you press start you add the event handler to the timer, but on stop you don't remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click start you are executing the line:

```
query1Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(doQuery1);
```

This adds a new event handler each time it is called causing your `doQuery1` method to be executed multiple times